# How to read multiple images from a folder in python(using opencv)?

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following  images = readImages(imgFolder, "frame", NIMGS+1, ".png"). I want to define readImages to read multiple images from a folder with each image being a frame from a sequence of images, NIMGS is just the number of total images, and obviously .png is the filetype. How would I go about defining readImages?

**Update:**

```py
def readImages(imgFolder, frame, numberImages,fileType):
    imagelist = np.zeros((1,numberImages+1),dtype = 'float32')
    for curr in range(0,numberImages,1):
        imagelist = np.append(cv2.imread(imgFolder + 'frame' + str(curr) + \ '.png'))
    return imagelist
```

Comment: Why dont you use a loop with result stored in the array and at each iteration append the accessed image into the array. You will need to have a list of image names as strings and then use simple ```imread()``` method and then append it into your array. So if you want to access the first image you can do the same by indexing the respective position in the array.

Comment: Could I try something like I posted in the update of the original post?

Comment: Why dont you try that out?

Comment: I get an error for trying to append an np array

Comment: Append  method in numpy is : ```numpy.append(arr, values, axis=None)```, here array will be your variable where you want to append, values will be image read by you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I believe I have figured it out.

Comment: Thats good, if you have figured out.